# No puedo configurar R en VS code (linux)

Tags: r, linux, vscode, archlinux

he intendado configurar R en VS code, baje la extensión de Yuki Ueda y el LSP client, tambien instale el paquete de languageserver, pero al poner el path para la terminal (r.termpath) me aparece le siguiente mensaje:
"Cannot find R client at /usr/lib64/R/bin/R"
Que es donde me marca R.home() que esta el ejecutable.
Tambien intente con radian, pero no encuentro un ejecutable, solo un script.

Me podrian ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SO! ya intentaste conseguir el ejecutable con `which`?

Comment: Hola! Si ya tambien lo intente y no funciono

Comment: Además de VSCode y las extensiones, ¿habéis descargado R? https://cran.r-project.org/

Comment: Claro que lo tengo descargado, puedo iniciarlo sin problemas desde la terminal